# How to identify if member of a group is a user or group in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

```
var result = grpResponse.Entries[0];

if (result.Attributes["member"] != null)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < result.Attributes["member"][i].ToString()
}
```

The above code Will get all the members of a group. i.e., group may contains group and users.

How to get only users?

Comment: How you differentiate group by user?

Comment: user have entries and groups does not. So I am getting exception while adding user details.

Comment: What line you get the exception? The loop wont compile either, is this complete code?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - limit to the OU you're interested in
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "OU=YourOU,DC=YourCompany,DC=Com"))
{
    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           UserPrincipal up = p as UserPrincipal;

           if (up != null) 
           {
               Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
               // do whatever you need to do with that user principal
           }
       }
    }
}
```

You cannot get *just* the users from a group's membership - you need to filter after you get the results back.

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You should have a type that gives you

```
#microsoft.graph.user
```

For users. So  This is if you're using the office graph. There might be different ways of doing it, but this at least is one of them.

Comment: Everything and nothing. Like I said, it all depends on how you're querying your AD. In my example I used the office graph, which basically lets you traverse AD and query anything from users to groups, group memberships and all the way to documents. I can use the "members" query to get a list of members for a group, and the TYPE of member will then specify if it's a user or a group or something else. As I wrote in my answer, there are other ways of doing it too, but it is ONE of the answers to your question. That downvote does not make sense to me.